# Using View to add divider in listView

Tags: android, listview

I am using a view to add a customized divider to listview.
I have a problem,I want to hide the divider which comes before the first list item.
Any suggestions how to do this?
 [image: Listview]

I don't want that divider over first item (Akshay) should be visible.

Help me. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<!-- ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       />

 </LinearLayout>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow"

    />

 <!--User's Name-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom ="10dip"
    android:text="hhs"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<!-- chat-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Hi how are you"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you using listview or listfragment ?

Comment: for api level 11+ you can use android:divider="" and dividerHeight attributes from xml itself

Comment: @IllegalArgument I know. I wanted to margin from left and right and it was not possible without adding this view.

Comment: in that case follow @anuj answer that is sureshot to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this approach for custom divider

you need to check the position of the `cell` in your `getView()` and accordingly you can from your code hide/show your custom divider

```
 if(childPosition==0)//is first child
    {
        YOURDIVIDER.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        YOURDIVIDER.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

you need to find your divider view for this, before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ListView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:dividerHeight="1px">
 </ListView>
```

Comment: I want margin from left and right as in the pic above.Not possible this way in <ListView>

Comment: than you have to use your custom adapter and put your getview code

Answer (score 1):

in your custom adapter class where you setting value to the custom layout in  getView method

check position of layout if it is 0 then set its visibility GONE or INVISIBLE as per your requirement

for that create object of VIEW of divider and set its setVisibility() method

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
```

Comment: I hope u have removed the default divider for listview

Comment: I removed default divider,neither it is visible in the pic above.
And ya setting android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", its sets the divider to the bottom,which makes the divider appear after the last item also.

@Anuj's soltn worked. :)